# how would i rewrite this code so it can display three different messages?

Tags: java

How could I rewrite this code so that I can display: "You are a teenager" for teenagers,              "You are a kid" for those who are 12 and younger, "You are an adult” for those who are older than 19?

```
 int age = 15; 

 if (age >= 13)

 if (age <= 19)    

 System.out.printf("Your are a teenager\n");
```

Comment: First please show us your attempt.

Comment: You could at least indent your code properly

Comment: Think about it logically.  A teenager is between 13 and 19 years of age, so you need some way of providing a range, something more like `if age > 12 and age < 20 then you are a teenager`. Take a look at [IF for beginners](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_if_statements.html) and see if you can apply it ;)

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
if (age <= 12) 
    System.out.printf("You are a kid\n");
else if (age <= 19)    
    System.out.printf("You are a teenager\n");
else
    System.out.printf("You are an adult\n");
```

Comment: Perhaps because you're teaching the original poster that if they post their homework on this sight without showing any effort, someone will do it for them. Why not see what they can do first and then guide *them* to an answer rather than spoon feeding one to them?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Doesn't the issue then lie with the question, and not the answer?